# Meaning of "cored down"

Tags: meaning

> “The guy was a fruit, but he wasn’t hurting anyone,” Boutillier said. “So hi-ho-the-dairy-o, along come these three pusholes in their engineer boots and they steal his life. I’m going to put them in the slam, my friend, and if I hear they got their puckery little assholes **cored down** there at Thomaston, I’m gonna send them cards saying I hope whoever did it had AIDS.”
> It by Stephen King

Could you guys tell me what is the meaning of "cored down" here? The only reference that I could find of "core" used in a sexual way was this entry on the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cored). Thank you.

Comment: That's about the only way you can interpret that.

Comment: "Cored down" isn't a phrasal verb; "down there at Thomaston" is a single locative adjunct.

Comment: 'Coring' seems to be used in [archaeology](http://biggararchaeology.org.uk/biggar-archaeology-news-coring-the-valley-floor/), but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: You have misparsed the sentence. Because ***cored down* is not a syntactic constituent**, asking for its meaning is a meaningless question based upon a bad parse.

Comment: By the time you get to the "if I hear they got their puckery little assholes **X**," you could see the word *caressed* or *pressed* and you'd know who's getting what in an unwelcome way.

Answer (score 2):

You have split the sentence wrongly:

{if I hear they got their puckery little assholes cored} {down there at Thomaston,}

**To core** has the meaning given in the Urban Dictionary:

> **cored**
>
> **When someone has had sex with someone or something so large that their cavity remains open, often painfully.**
>
> Girl: *The guy last night was really big, he cored me.* by Kinglink January 22, 2010

The verb is probably a figurative use of "to core" as used in founding:

OED **to core**

> **3.** Founding. **To mould or cast with a core. to core out: to hollow out by using a core.**
>
> 1902   Westm. Gaz. 4 June 5/1   *Its bottom is cored out to fit over
> the nose of the projectile itself.*